# port bind AECCES in openshift node.js service for installing mediawiki parsoid

Tags: node.js, port, openshift, mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I am trying to launch the mediawiki parsoid module, which runs over openshift cloud node.js service [as writen in the extension page](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Parsoid/Setup). When I launch Server.js, I get `Bind AECCES` message, which I assume to be caused by port configuration problem I have'nt been able to solve.

I am not much familiar with the issue of port listening in openshift NODE.JS and I will be very thankfull for such guidance.